# Internet Connection not being picked up

Tags: networking, internet, network-manager, ethernet, gedit

My dad has ubuntu installed on his PC, and up to now we haven't had any issues with it. However a couple of days ago it auto-updated to a new version of ubuntu. Looking at the details in settings, it said it was 14.04. After this update the PC would not pickup the ethernet cable that was connected, therefore we couldn't use the internet.

After searching the internet for a solution I found one that involved opening gksudo, using gedit as root user and changing the text in the netowrkmanager config file IFUPDOWN Managed = False, from false to true.

After this fix I was able to get the internet running, however every time I restarted the system the network would show as unmanaged, despite the config file still saying true. At this point we have to open gksudo, gedit as root user, open networkmanager config file, and save it again. This would make the network usable and allow access to the internet via a browser. This would also need to be repeated everytime the PC was re-booted. Whilst this was a little tedious it was a satisfying fix. However today my dad tried to use the software center and has found that this is showing up as not having a network connection, making it impossible to download any software. If anyone has any idea's what to do to fix this then please help, as so far this is baffling me.

Thanks in advance
Stephen